# Append content to root element of Window

Tags: wpf

Years late, I know, but new to WPF here.

I am trying to append a new element to another windows content without overriding it.

So for example, let's just say I want to add a border that fits the ActualWidth/ActualHeight of Window1 I can do so with `Window1.Content = new Border Content`

But I want to append to Window1 content without overriding it

Lets say Window1:

```
....
 <Grid>
  This is Window1 content root that possesses many children
 </Grid>
...
```

And in Window2 constructor:

```
public Window2(Window owner) {
    this.Owner = owner;

    //add element to root of Window1 (owner) fixed position 
}
```

So I have done some research on VisualTree traversing but there doesn't seem to be a documented way to add elements to the owners root element, unless you know it's type.

The problem there, is adding children to those elements are dependent methods. For example adding a child to StackPanel is not the same method as adding a new row to a Grid then adding children to that row.

Is there a way to append to content and emulate a 'fixed' positioned element like the border for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word, "no". That's just not how WPF works. Most WPF controls ultimately subclass ContentControl, which supports only a single Content object:

```
    public object Content { get; set; }
```

That's why you'll get an error if you try to do something like this:

```
<Window x:Class="MyWpApp.MainWindow" ... etc...>

    <TextBlock Text="Hello World!" />
    <TextBlock Text="Goodbye World!" />

</Window>
```

ContentControl does contain an `AddChild` function, but again you'll get an error if you call it when it already has a child (i.e. `System.InvalidOperationException: 'Content of a ContentControl must be a single element.'`).

The way you get around this is to set the child to something that subclasses the abstract class `Panel`, which does support multiple children:

```
public UIElementCollection Children { get; }
```

This is the base class that things like Grid, StackPanel etc subclass. So if you know a window has already set one as it's only child content you can do something something like this:

```
(this.Content as Panel).AddChild(newChildControl);
```

That's probably the closest you'll get to what you're looking for, but obviously you need to make sure you've actually set a Panel as the content to begin with.